# Kotlin Coroutines: suspending subsequent access token renewal requests

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an app which authenticates with a back-end and receives a long-lived refresh token and short-lived access token back. We use the access token for authorizing our requests, and every time it expires, we trigger a token renewal (using the refresh token) before we retry the API call with the new tokens. Pretty standard stuff.

It's possible to trigger multiple network calls simultaneously (asynchronously), but if they all have invalid access tokens, we want only the first to go through and refresh the token, while the subsequent calls wait for the initial one to complete before they continue. Currently, we've implemented it like this:

```kotlin
private var renewingDeferred: Deferred<Unit>? = null

suspend fun renewTokens() {
    coroutineScope {
        if (renewingDeferred == null) {
            renewingDeferred = async {
                try {
                    tokens = tokensApi.renew().await()
                } finally {
                    renewingDeferred = null
                }
            }
        } else {
            renewingDeferred?.await()
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that every request that has an invalid access token will call `renewTokens()` and then retry with new headers. The caller of `renewTokens()` shouldn't care about whether it actually renews or just waits for a previous renewal to finish, as long as it knows that tokens are renewed once the function returns (is no longer suspended). And as far as I can tell, it works fine, but I'm not completely sure about the code, specifically the `renewingDeferred = null` part of the `finally` block.

For instance, say  request A starts renewing, request B is triggered and starts awaiting request A, then A finishes, sets `renewingDeferred` to `null`, but does setting that value to `null` somehow affect request B's awaiting status?

Also, what if an exception is thrown when calling the API? I don't have a `catch` block, sort of assuming that `await()`ing on a deferred that throws will somehow rethrow, but exception handling in coroutines isn't really my strong side. Would love to get some advice on this.

Also, if anyone has a general idea about how this should be solved in a different manner, all suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using Mutex.
Create one property for coroutine locking, and when renewToken is called, lock Mutex until token is renewed.